# Preprocessor directives

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

When we see `#include <iostream>`, it is said to be a *preprocessor directive*.

`#include` ---> directive

And, I think:

`<iostream>` ---> preprocessor

But, what is meant by "preprocessor" and "directive"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It may help to think of the relationship between a "directive" and being "given directions" (i.e. orders).  "preprocessor directives" are directions to the *preprocessor* about changes it should make to the code before the later stages of compilation kick in.

But, what's the preprocessor?  Well, its name reflects that it processes the source code before the "main" stages of compilation.  It's simply there to process the textual source code, modifying it in various ways.  The preprocessor doesn't even understand the tokens it operates on - it has no notion of types or variables, classes or functions - it's all just quoted- and/or parentheses- grouped, comma- and/or whitespace separated text to be manhandled.  This extra process gives more flexibility in selecting, combining and even generating parts of the program.

EDIT addressing @SWEngineer's comment:  Many people find it helpful to think of the preprocessor as a separate program that modifies the C++ program, then gives its output to the "real" C++ compiler (this is pretty much the way it used to be).  When the preprocessor sees `#include <iostream>` it thinks *"ahhha - this is something I understand, I'm going to take care of this and not just pass it through blindly to the C++ compiler"*.  So, it searches a number of directories (some standard ones like `/usr/include` and wherever the compiler installed its own headers, as well as others specified using `-I` on the command line) looking for a file called "iostream".  When it finds it, it then replaces the line in the input program saying "#include " with the complete contents of the file called "iostream", adding the result to the output.  BUT, it then moves to the first line it read from the "iostream" file, looking for more directives that it understands.

So, the preprocessor is very simple.  It can understand `#include`, `#define`, `#if`/`#elif`/`#endif`, `#ifdef` and `$ifndef`, `#warning` and `#error`, but not much else.  It doesn't have a clue what an "`int`" is, a template, a class, or any of that "real" C++ stuff.  It's more like some automated editor that cuts and pastes parts of files and code around, preparing the program that the C++ compiler proper will eventually see and process.  The preprocessor is still very useful, because it knows how to find parts of the program in all those different directories (the next stage in compilation doesn't need to know anything about that), and it can remove code that might work on some other computer system but wouldn't be valid on the one in use.  It can also allow the program to use short, concise macro statements that generate a lot of real C++ code, making the program more manageable.

Comment: @Tony. Can you just explain it in terms of for example "#include <iostream>" as an example? Since I'm almost getting it. Thanks.

Comment: @Tony. ("preprocessor directives" are directions to the preprocessor about changes it should make to the code before the later stages of compilation kick in). What are examples of changes here? Thanks.

Comment: @Tony. Sorry for my many questions here. Regarding the "Preprocessor", can you just describe it in a bit more detail? Thanks.

Comment: @SWEngineer: I've tried to explain a bit better above.  Hope that helps.  I've got somewhere else to be though - might not check online for hours or days... sorry.  Hope it's enough.

Comment: @Tony. Thanks a lot for your nice explanation, really appreciate it. Just a small thing when you find sometime. When you say: "BUT, it next moves to the first line it read from the "iostream" file, looking for more directives that it understands.". What about the other preprocessor directives in the .cpp file to be compiled and run? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SWEngineer: Well, remember I said it inserts iostream in place of the "#include <iostream>" line?  So, it then processes lines that came from iostream, but the original lines from the file containing that include statement still continue aftwerwards.  You might say it allows itself to be sidetracked by the iostream file content, but remembers to return to what it was doing beforehand.

Comment: To give an everyday example: imagine you're reading a book, but whenever you find something interesting, you want to look up further details in a book specialising in that topic.  So, you put the first book spine-down but still open to the page you're reading.  If you're then reading the second book, and find something interesting in there, you put it spine down on top of the earlier book, open to the page in there that you're reading, and pick up yet another book.  As you complete additional "research" without finding new things of interest, you close books and pick up earlier ones...

Comment: eventually, you get to the point where you've finished the first book.  A C++ program is a bit like that in that it includes stuff from other files, and they can include yet other files: the whole thing forms a kind of "tree" where one file can "branch" into including many others, and each branch can branch again, but in the end you pull in all the branches and there's the complete "translation unit" (enough C++ to produce one "object", could be a library or a program or something ready to link to form a program).

Answer (score 8):

`#include` is the *preprocessor directive*, `<iostream>` is just an *argument* supplied in addition to this directive, which in this case happens to be a file name.

Some preprocessor directives take arguments, some don't, e.g.

```
#define FOO 1

#ifdef _NDEBUG
    ....
#else
    ....
#endif

#warning Untested code !
```

The common feature is that they all start with `#`.

In *Olden Times* the preprocessor was a separate tool which pre-processed source code before passing it to the compiler front-end, performing macro substitutions and including header files, etc. These days the pre-processor is usually an integral part of the compiler, but it essentially just does the same job.

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor directives, such as `#define` and `#ifdef`, are typically used to make source programs easy to change and easy to compile in different execution environments. Directives in the source file tell the preprocessor to perform specific actions. For example, the preprocessor can replace tokens in the text, insert the contents of other files into the source file...

`#include` is a preprocessor directive meaning that it is use by the *preprocessor* part of the compiler. This happens 'before' the compilation process. The `#include` needs to specify 'what' to include, this is supplied by the argument `iostream`. This tells the preprocessor to include the file `iostream.h`.

More information:

- [Preprocessor Directives on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3sxhs2ty%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)
- [Preprocessor directives on cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/)

Comment: "The #include needs to specify 'what' to include, this is supplied by the argument iostream. This tells the preprocessor to include the file iostream.h." No, it doesn't. It tells the preprocessor to include the file `iostream`.