# What is The Use Of # in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c

i would like to know the usage of # in C or C++..... please can u inform me what is the purpose of # or Why it is used?

Comment: It's one half step better than C?

Comment: #, used in conjunction with C, is a very popular programming language of Microsoft ;-)

Comment: see also here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757107/preprocessor-directives

Comment: -1 This question shows zero research effort.

Answer (score 14):

In C/C++, the `#` sign marks preprocessor directives.

If you're not familiar with the preprocessor, it works as part of the compilation process, handling includes, macros, and more.  It actually adds code to the source file before the final compilation.  If you're using gcc/g++, you can see what the preprocessor generates by using the `-E` flag.

#### Example preprocessor directives:

**Includes:**

```
#include <iostream>
```

Includes are used to insert the contents of the included file into the current file at the location of the directive.

**Constants:**

```
#define RANDOM_NUMBER 4
```

During processing, every instance of `RANDOM_NUMBER` in the file will be textually replaced with `4`

**Conditional compilation:**

```
#ifdef DEBUG
printf( "Random number: %d", RANDOM_NUMBER );
#endif
```

In this case, the print statement will only be a part of the compiled program if the `DEBUG` macro has been defined.

Answer (score 6):

It is used for all the preprocessor directives, like #include, #ifdef and all the others

Comment: It is used for preprocessor directives (#include, #if, #else, #elif, #endif, #define, #undef, #error, #ifdef, #ifndef, # (null directive), #pragma) as well as the stringizing operator '#' and the token pasting operator '##'. Plus within character ('#') and string ("#") constants. Anywhere else it is a syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

`#` can be used to represent the [mesh character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octothorpe):

```
char mesh = '#';
```

It can also be misused to generate syntax errors:

```
char#mesh; // error: stray '#' in program
```

Comment: Also a wall, if you can't be bothered to lookup block character codepoints.