# C language: meaning of operator "#" ?

Tags: c

This code can be compiled by `gcc -g -o main main.c`, no warnings.

```
// main.c
# 41 "stdio.h"
# 22
#
int main(void){
    (void)printf("foo");
    return 0;
}
```

My question is:

1. What is the meaning of operator "#" before "include". We use `#include <stdio.h>` to include the header file,  why not `include <stdio.h>` ?
2. Why `# 22` or `# 41` can be compiled, I have never seen it before.

Anybody can help me ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110683/what-is-the-use-of-in-c-or-c

check this bro

Comment: @mkpchiran: Your link doesn’t explain the above issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like the output of the preprocessor. The line

```
# 41 "stdio.h"
```

can be interpreted like:

- 41 has the meaning:

> It specifies the line number which should be reported for the following line of input. Subsequent lines are counted from linenum.

- `"stdio.h"` is just the filename from which the lines are taken.

> The following line and all subsequent lines are
>   reported to come from the file it specifies, until something else happens to
>   change that. filename is interpreted according to the normal rules for a string
>   constant: backslash escapes are interpreted.

And all this information is taken from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Line-Control.html#Line-Control and https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html#Preprocessor-Output

For the single `#`:

> The null directive consists of a ‘#’ followed by a newline, with only whitespace (including comments) in between. A null directive is understood as a preprocessing directive but has no effect on the preprocessor output. The primary significance of the existence of the null directive is that an input line consisting of just a ‘#’ will produce no output, rather than a line of output containing just a ‘#’. Supposedly some old C programs contain such lines.

taken from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Other-Directives.html#Other-Directives

Answer (score 2):

A `#` at the start of a line introduces a preprocessing directive. Preprocessing is conceptually an earlier stage of translation than compilation, which is why it uses an easily-recognisable syntax.

If the `#` is followed by *anything other than* `include`, `define`, `undef`, `line`, `error` or `pragma`, then it is a *non-directive* (6.10p1), and is ignored.

This means that `#` at the start of a line is a simple way for the compiler to pass information between stages of translation; here it is being used to pass source file and line number information.